# MEAN stack app implementation in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are developing an ecommerce application with POS in place. Here is my preferred application structure

2 server with node which will manage both ecommerce back end and pos backend
1 server with angular js which will run both frontend 
1 server with MongoDB

Now I am planning to implement the same structure with Amazon AWS EB. Can any one help me with the structure for the server that how can I implement that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk doesn't lend itself well to a traditional n-tier architecture. The base unit of EB is the application, which contains one or more environments. Each environment consists of one or more instances, and environments can be scaled up or down automatically. Within an environment, each instance has the same code deployed.

So, you could theoretically define three separate EB applications (eCommerce back end, PoS back end, and Angular front end) as well as a MongoDB instance running separately on EC2. (Neither EB nor RDS support MongoDB at the moment.)

However, I don't think you'd be gaining much from EB in that case, unless you need auto-scaling. It might make more sense for you to explore AWS' other deployment tools (CloudFormation perhaps?) instead.

Alternately, if you could combine your servers into a single instance, then EB might make a lot of sense.